# Google Merchant Center - retrieve the BestSellers_TopProducts_ report without the BigQuery Data Transfer service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, report, google-merchant-center

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve a specific Google Merchant Center report (BestSellers_TopProducts_) and upload it to BigQuery as part of a specific ETL process we're developing for a customer we have at my workplace.

So far, I know you can set up the BigQuery Data Transfer service so it automates the process of downloading this report but I was wondering if I could accomplish the same with Python and some API libraries from Google (like `python-google-shopping`) but I may be overdoing it and setting up the service is the way to go.

Is there a way to accomplish this rather than resorting to the aforementioned service?

On the other hand, and assuming the BigQuery Data Transfer service is the way to go, I see (in the examples) you need to create and provide the dataset you're going to extract the report data to so I guess the extraction is limited to the GCP project you're working with.

I mean... you can't extract the report data for a third-party even if you had the proper service account credentials, right?

Comment: You can use [manual integration](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/connecting-merchant-center-to-bigquery#manual_integration) to transfer data from Google merchant Center to BigQuery.Can you mention from where you want to extract report data for which third party? Let me know if manual integration is helpful or not?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar thank you very much for the time you took to answer my question but the problem I have is I need to give my customer (I can't reveal the name) potential insights on competitor product offers and everything I see on the documentation pertaining the Shopping Content API is about handling/managing your own products which is not what I need :(

Comment: Hii @Julio Maria Meca Hansen, You can use [Python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) client libraries for BigQuery Data Transfer. For your requirement you can check [price competitiveness reports](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9626903) in Google Merchant Center.
Let me know if that is helpful or not?